# Conditional dependency with pip and setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a package that is dependent on another package that can use two equivalent api's to work. For licensing reasons I need the package to use a particular api. The author of said package has been so kind to include in his `setup.py`

```
try:
    import correct_license
except ImportError:
    install_requires.append('WrongLicense>=0.04.16')
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with `pip` on a clean install and dependencies listed in `install_requires`. This is due to the fact that pip installs packages in isolation and there (seems to be) is no way to influence the installation.

We tried to use environment variables in the past. These make a very bad user experience, as they suffer from the same problem. The only way to make these work is to have the user set the environment variable in his own environment. You cannot use `os.environ['xxx']`.

What can I do that does not involve user interaction but does solve the problem? We are now looking at vendoring in the modules, but this is really a last resort.

Comment: The other package should use optional extras, instead. You can then use `package[foo]` or `package[bar]` to tell pip to install the package and a specific extra dependency.

Comment: The setuptools / pip infrastructure otherwise has no tools to specify multiple packages as providing an equivalent API.

Comment: See https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies for how to declare extras.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that would require the user to make a choice for the original package, which is not what that author wants.

Comment: Then you are out of options, sorry. The setuptools dependency options just don't offer that much flexibility.